# Get number of occurrences of array elements with each other in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to get the number of times two elements occurs together in an array. My table looks like this:

```
id    districts
---------------------------------------
1     {district1, district2}
2     {district1, district2, district3}
3     {district5, district2, district4}
4     {district2, district3, district1}
5     {district1, district5, district3}
...
```

I want to get the number of times districts have been in the same array together. So the result for this example would be:

```
district1, district2, 2
district1, district3, 1
district1, district3, 3
...
```

I need this for all of the combinations of them. Any suggestions on how to get any result like this would be a great help

Comment: Your table structure should follow atleast basic normalization that all the data should be atomic and then it wouldnt become complex to achieve the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnest, join, and aggregate:

```
with d as (
      select t.id, district
      from d cross join lateral
           unnest(districts) district
     )
select d1.district, d2.district, count(*) as cooccurrences
from d d1 join
     d d2
     on d1.id = d2.id and d1.district < d2.district
group by d1.district, d2.district
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally,  You can make use of a corelated subquery  if your data is proper

```
     Select 
      distinct districts, count(*) 
     from table t where districts IN
 ( Select districts from table where 
     districts  like '%' ||t.districts||'%') ;
```